# Anaconda / Conda Navigator: No other environments than root

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda

I can create environments via command line, but they are not shown in Anaconda Navigator. Even if I create environments through Anaconda Navigator - they will be created, but aren't shown in Anaconda Navigator. When launching jupyter through Anaconda Navigator I don't get offered the different conda kernels in jupyter. Where could be the problem? I'm using Windows.

Comment: Create a test env real quick, by running: conda create --name testenv. And since you're on Windows you don't run "source activate" but simply "activate." Try running: activate testenv